# Reading excel column with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using python 3 jupyter notebook with pandas. I use the following code to read the first two columns of a given sheet in an excel file. I get a ValueError.

```
tagsFull = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Full',
    names = ['Tag', 'Description'], usecols="A,B")
```

ValueError: ',' is not in list

if i write :

```
usecols=["A,B"]
```

ValueError: ',' is not in list

and if i write :

```
usecols=["A","B"]
```

ValueError: 'B' is not in list

[edit] it was a version issue as jpp indicated. Using parse_cols instead of usecols worked fine.

Comment: Try `usecols=["A,B"]`

Answer (score 1):

try `usecols` with list of columns `["A","B"]`

```
tagsFull = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx',
sheet_name='Full',
names = ['Tag', 'Description'], usecols=["A","B"])
```